# Maximum Ranks in Speak Language?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

Is Speak Langauges subject to the same maximum rank as other skills? I.e., at level 1 with speak languages as a class skill, how many languages can I learn? 4, or more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Exceedingly unclear

The rules never really say. Speak Language is listed like a skill, and you put skill points into it like a skill, and it can even be a *class* skill, but you don’t really end up with ranks in it, so it’s kind of impossible to say.

The DM has to make a choice. For what it’s worth, the best information we’ve got is this:

> You can purchase Speak Language just like any other skill, but **instead of buying a rank** in it, you choose a new language that you can speak.

This implies that you don’t have ranks, which means there is no number that can exceed 3 + your level, and thus you can never hit the limit while learning as many languages as you like.

Your total languages known is definitely not limited by the maximum rank limit, since at level 1 that limit is four, and starting with five or more is pretty easy (Int 18 on anything, Int 16 on anything with two Automatic Languages, etc.).

Comment: For feat prerequisites, this was, for official *D&D 3.5* material anyway, strangely consistent: no feat has as its prerequisite Speak Language X ranks, instead requiring Speak Language (# of languages) or Speak Language (specific language). Usually there's at least *one* exception, but not in this. It's oddly comforting.